# Core Data Group By and Search for Properties of one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an application with two core data entities:

Products and Properties.

Each product has a set of properties which is a one-to-many relationship in the model.

I want to do a few things:

- A product has a brand_id, and a brand name. I want to get a list of all brand names, possibly by grouping all products by their brand_id.
- I then want to get all unique keys from all products associated to that brand. So, select all products with a certain brand_id and then select all properties associated with any of the products, and then group them by their key.
- After that, I want to select one particular key value pair to search for, and get all products associated with a property matching that key value pair.

Is any of this even possible with core data? I've been searching high and low, but it seems this problem is a little more complex than what most people have to do.

Comment: Why don't you have a `Brand` entity?

Comment: I agree with @Wain, this sounds more like a modeling problem. You should have a Brand object associated with your products. Core Data is an Object Graph, not a database. Treating it with database gloves will cause difficult to solve issues like this which in turn will create poorly performing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first 2 questions I would suggest to create another Brand entity and make proper relations in your model. That will definitely make it much easier.

Make sure you have invert relation from Brand to products - that will automatically give you answer for first 2 questions.

You can search for distinct (unique) values in core data using:

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"distinctProperty"]];
```

For finding products that has properties matching key, value pair you should use this NSPredicate while fetching Product entities:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(properties, $property, $property.key == %@ AND $property.value == %@).@count > 0)", @"keySearch", @"valueSearch"];
```